# Should this be ambiguous or not? (implicit casts)

Tags: c++, standards, casting

```
 struct A 
 {
     A(const A& src);
     A(const char* src);
 };
 struct B 
 {
     operator A();
     operator char*();
 };
 void test()  
 {
     B v;
     A s(v);
 }
```

EDG/Comeau and MSVC allows the code while GCC 4.4.4, CLANG and BCC
reject it as ambiguous.

A C++ committee member replied with this (initially):

> It's not ambiguous; the A(const A&)
>   constructor is better than the A(const
>   char*) constructor. The const A&
>   parameter binds directly to the result
>   of the conversion function, so the
>   conversion sequence is considered to
>   be a user-defined conversion followed
>   by an identity conversion
>   (13.3.3.1.4p1). The const char*
>   parameter is a user-defined conversion
>   followed by a qualification
>   conversion, so it's worse.

Then, he followed up with this.

> Actually, I was wrong. While it is
>   true that the second conversion
>   sequence in a user-defined conversion
>   sequence is a tiebreaker, looking more
>   closely at 13.3.3.2p3, the
>   next-to-last bullet, reveals that this
>   tiebreaker only applies if the two
>   sequences contain the same
>   user-defined conversion sequence, and
>   that is not the case in this example.
>   Because one constructor's conversion
>   sequence uses B::operator A() and the
>   other uses b::operator char*(),
>   there's no tiebreaker between the two
>   user-defined conversion sequences and
>   they are ambiguous.

My question is this.

13.3.3.2 p3 states that,

> Two implicit conversion sequences of
>   the same form are indistinguishable
>   conversion sequences unless one of the
>   following rules apply.

From my understanding, the keywords are "one of the following rules".
It doesn't mean that the bullet which states "same conversion sequence"
overrides all the ones above. I would've thought "the rank of S1 is better
than the rank of S2" would be applicable instead?

Comment: Fine proof that C++ got it a tiny bit too complicated...

Comment: Since you have a c++ community member contact, shouldn't you just ask him to file an issue? (or check if it is filed at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html )

Comment: I didn't say there's an issue, I'm actually trying to understand the standards.

Comment: What would be interesting would be to know which conversion EDG and MSVC allowed. But it's one of the reasons I don't like implicit conversions, if I need a conversion, I'll ask for it thanks.

Comment: explicit = good, implicit = bad

Comment: explicit = clean, implicit = ugly. You are trying to understand an improper part of the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the expected result is Ambiguity to the best of my interpretation of Clause 13.3.3.2

Matching argument 'v' of type 'B' to the parameters of either of the overloaded constructors of 'A' requires a user defined conversion. There both the sequences are of CONVERSION rank.

My interpretation is that the following quote from $13.3.3.2 applies

> [...]User-defined conversion sequence
>   U1 is a better conversion sequence
>   than another user-defined conversion
>   sequence U2 **if they contain the same
>   user-defined conversion function or
>   constructor *and* if the second standard
>   conversion sequence of U1 is better
>   than the second standard conversion
>   sequence of U2.**

Both of these invoke different conversion functions in class 'B'. Therefore, I think the first condition itself is not satisfied and hence the expected result is Ambiguity as nither of the conversion sequences is better than the other.

Comment: Yes this is clearly ambiguous, for the exact reason you mention. I'm not sure why this isn't the accepted answer. It directly points how why and that it is ambiguous. However it is wrong that it has "conversion" rank. As you later say, you have two user defined conversion sequences. Ranks are given to standard conversion sequences (exact match, promotion, conversion). There is no notion of a rank for user defined conversion sequence.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Disclaimer : the standard is really complex on these parts, so I may be completely wrong in my understanding.</strike>

Standard definition of the *best* viable function (13.3.3) :

> Given these definitions, a viable
>   function F1 is defined to be a better
>   function than another viable function
>   F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is
>   not a worse conversion sequence than
>   ICSi(F2), and then
>
> [...]
>
> - the context is **an initialization by user-defined conversion** (see 8.5,
>     13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) and the standard conversion sequence from the
>     return type of F1 **to the destination
>     type** (i.e., the type of the entity
>     being initialized) is a better
>     conversion sequence than the standard
>     conversion sequence from the return
>     type of F2 to the destination type.

If I understand correctly, the type of the object being constructed has its importance here, and that would make `A::A(const A &)` a better candidate.

---

Refer to Johannes comments to see why this answer is incorrect : this is indeed ambiguous for the reason pointed out by Chubsdad.

Comment: Definitely relevant, +1, but of the 2 contexts mentioned, 13.3.1.5 concerns only initialisation of non-class types (like `int`) and 13.3.1.6 concerns only initialisation of *references*.  So I don't think they apply here.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: yes but 8.5 does cover initialization or pretty much everything else

Comment: @icecrime: You're right, but the plot thickens: According to 8.5/12, `A s(v);` is *direct-initialisation* -- right?  Then the 6th bullet of 8.5/14 applies.  It's too big to quote here, but the key point is that it does not mention the words "user-defined conversion" -- *unlike* the next bullet covering (some) copy-initialisation cases.  So I don't think the snippet you quoted applies here, and I conclude that `A s(v);` is ambiguous but `A s = v;` should select the `A(const A&)` ctor.

Comment: I further conclude that C++'s rules for initialisation could not possibly be more confusing.

Comment: Yeah, it's down to interpretation whether your 1st snippet applies...  The fact that it explicitly mentions 13.3.1.5 and 13.3.1.6 but *not* 13.3.1.3 (which is the relevant clause in this case) makes me think it doesn't; but OTOH a user-defined conversion is clearly taking place, so maybe it does.  The root problem is that "initialization by user-defined conversion" is not actually a term that is defined anywhere AFAICT.

Comment: @icecrime the text you quote from 13.3.3 does address another issue. `F1` and `F2` are conversion functions, like in the example shown in that paragraph. It defines what happens when for all parameters you can't find a winner by the first bullet, like in the following example: `struct A { operator char*(); operator char const*(); }; char const* x = A();`. The candidate set's parameter lists are (implicit object parameters) `{(A&), (A&)}` with the argument list being `(A)`. So by 13.3.3.2, both `ICS1(F1)` and `ICS1(F2)` are equally bad/good, so the rule you quoted gets into the game.

Comment: Your quote then compares `char* -> char const*` against `char const* -> char const*`, figuring that the second one is a proper subsequence of the first, meaning it is better. It will then therefor choose `operator char const*()` as the user defined conversion function within the user defined conversion sequence. The basic insight in the original code is: You run overload resolution multiple times, with nested contexts. The outer context is `13.3.1.3` with `Fn` being the contstructor `n`. The inner contexts are 13.3.1.4 (for param 1 of ctor 1) and 13.3.1.5 (for param 1 of ctor 2).

Comment: After you did overload resolution for the inner contexts, selecting `operator A` for param1/ctor1 an `operator char*` for param1/ctor2 (these conversion sequences for the nested overload resolutions for the two constructor parameters will be standard conversion sequences - i.e `B` -> `B&`), you then have two user defined conversion sequences that both use different conversion functions. You will notice that none of the bullets of 13.3.3 matches then.

Comment: If you have C++0x, you can do the following experiment: Try making one of the constructors a template with a default arg: `struct A { A(const A& src); template<typename = void> A(char const*); };`. In that case, "F1 is a non-template function and F2 is a function template specialization ..." would be taken, and F1 (first ctor) would be called because it would be the best viable function.

Comment: *If* you want to apply the quoted text to context 13.3.1.3, you have F1 being the first constructor and F2 being the second constructor. The quoted text then makes no sense (what is the return type of a constructor?).

Comment: @Johannes: thank you for this explanation, you are (once more) absolutely and depressingly correct. Answer edited (I'm not sure if I should delete it ?)