# How does operator overload resolution work in the presence of the new initializer sequence?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Source>
class ConvertProxy
{
    Source const* m_source;
public:
    ConvertProxy( Source const& source )
        : m_source( &source )
    {
    }

    template <typename Dest>
    operator Dest() const
    {
        return Dest(m_source->begin(), m_source->end());
    }
};

template <typename Source>
ConvertProxy<Source> convert( Source const& source )
{
    return ConvertProxy<Source>( source );
}

int
main()
{
    std::vector<int> src;
    for ( int i = 0; i != 5; ++ i ) {
        src.push_back( i );
    }
    std::vector<double> dest = convert( src );   /* XXX */
    for ( std::vector<double>::const_iterator i = dest.begin(), e = dest.end();
            i != e;
            ++ i ) {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

is this legal in C++11, or is the line marked `XXX` ambiguous?

The same question, but with the marked line replaced by:

```
std::vector<double> dest( convert( src ) );
```

or with

```
std::vector<double> dest;
dest = convert( src );
```

In pre-C++11, I think the second was illegal, but the other two
definitely were not.

FWIW: g++ (4.8.2) accepts the first, but not the other two (with
`-std=c++11`; otherwise it accepts the first and the third, but
not the second).  VS 2013 accepts all of them, but Intellisense
marks all of them are erroneous (which is what triggered my
interest: you get a nice red marking in the scrollbar, with
symbols underlined in red, but the code compiles perfectly).
In other words: three compilers, and three different behaviors.

(And for those who wonder as to why: this is a standard idiom
for getting the context—the left hand side of an assignment,
for example—involved in overload resolution.)

Comment: Your first replacement, `std::vector<double> dest(convert(src));` is possibly ambiguous, due to [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) issue.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper For the most vexing parse issue to be involved, `convert` would have to name a type.  It doesn't.  I think that the first replacement (the second version) is (and always has been) ambiguous for any type which has multiple constructors which can be invoked with a single argument.  Never the less, Visual studios 2013 accepts it (and invokes the conversion I want).  What I'm looking for is someone who can explain to me how the new `initializer_list` constructors intervene.  Some explination WRT the rvalue-ref ctor would be nice too, although I think I understand them.

Comment: The only place I can see `initializer_list` being used is in the return value: instead of `ConvertProxy<Source>(source)` you can just write `{source}` but thats because you know the type from the return. Also for this particular problem what's the point of ConvertProxy, why not to just use one convert function with typename destination.

Comment: [MSVC accepts the ambiguous conversions due to a non-standard extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263748/should-this-be-ambiguous-or-not-implicit-casts).

Comment: if you don't mind using auto, you can achieve something much simpler. Here is the code: http://ideone.com/WietLn, which utilizes initializer_list, r-value references, and range based loops. EDIT: you can change the reference to r-value refs for the return of convert but i didn't see any need for that.

Comment: @Gasim The error message (IIRC) said something about ambiguity when converting to `std::vector<double>`, and one of the constructors mentioned was the `initializer_list`.

Comment: @Gasim And `auto` sort of defeats the whole purpose of the code.  The whole idea is that the correct conversion will be called automatically, based on the target type.  (And of course, in the version with assignment, there's absolutely no way of using `auto`.)

Comment: @Casey I'm not sure I see how that article applies here.  When I write `std::vector<double> dest( convert( source ) );`, it's ambiguous, because `std::vector` has several one-argument constructors, and the compiler can't choose between instantiating the conversion function for `size_t`, `std::vector<double>` or `std::allocator<double>`.  I don't see how Microsoft chooses here (and the compiler in Intellisense says that it is an error).

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, I see your point. My response was a bit knee-jerk. This appears to be a different overloading extension in MSVC. (IIRC Intellisense uses the EDG compiler front end, it's not too rare to have it disagree with the MSVC compiler).

Comment: @Casey It's the first disagreement I've seen, but I'll have to admit that I do most of my editing in vim, and only crank up Visual Studios for debugging, so I'm not likely to have notices what Intellisense does.  On the other hand, I find it interesting that g++ does still something different than either Intellisense or the VS compiler.  So we've got three different interpretations of the standard from three different compilers.

Answer (score 0):

There is ambiguity on the side of the compiled code that must be resolved first, and I don’t think the C++11 standard added anything to that effect.

You should use the full definition of the container as a *template template* parameter for the substitution to match; with the most explicit one as:

```
template <typename T, typename A, template <typename, typename> class Dest>
operator Dest<T, A>() const 
{ 
    return Dest<T, A>(m_source->begin(), m_source->end()); 
}
```

All the three cases compile, and the substitution matches with

```
[T = double, A = allocator<double>, Dest = vector],
```

with an old gcc-4.1.2, and with the shiny new clang-3.4 - with and without the `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: I can't use the template template, since some of the containers that I have to support are non-standard, and don't have the same template parameters, or are not templates.

Comment: @JamesKanze Why can't you keep adding operator() definitions to satisfy all the possible matches?

Comment: Because I don't know in advance all possible matches.  And trying to do so more or less defeats the purpose of using templates to begin with.  (I've used this idiom a lot where it targets three or four particular types, in which case, I do manually overload for each of them, but that's not the case here.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I am not keen to get into a philosophical discussion, but in that case passing containers as template arguments seems the wrong choice to me. Especially if you not willing to accomodate the compiler with a `typename Dest` and a `typename <typename typename> Dest` overload. I understand that your example is a toy one, nevertheless - you use begin/end - could you revert to ranges instead of containers? Or rely on a T::value_type duck typing?

Comment: @JamesKanze Consider moving all the requirements into the body of the question.

Comment: The question doesn't concern the "requirements" of any of the code.  The question concerns what the standard says about overload resolution, given the code.  (And I don't see any problem using containers as template arguments.  They are expressedly designed to support this use.)